# Why doesn't this .each block return the same as .select?

Tags: ruby, select, each

From CodeQuizzes #6: Create a new array from the captain_planet array with all the elements that contain the letter "a".

```
captain_planet = ["earth", "fire", "wind", "water", "heart"]
```

I understand their answer:

```
captain_planet.select do |word|
  word.include?("a")
end
```

But, I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't return the same thing:

```
ret = []

captain_planet.each do |x|
    if x.include?('a')
        ret.push(x)
    end
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You are seeing the return value of each. Try adding `p ret` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try seeing the output of ret after the end of the block.

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > ret = []
 => []
2.0.0p247 :002 > captain_planet = ["earth", "fire", "wind", "water", "heart"]
 => ["earth", "fire", "wind", "water", "heart"]
2.0.0p247 :003 > captain_planet.each do |x|
2.0.0p247 :004 >         if x.include?('a')
2.0.0p247 :005?>             ret.push(x)
2.0.0p247 :006?>         end
2.0.0p247 :007?>   end
 => ["earth", "fire", "wind", "water", "heart"]
2.0.0p247 :008 > puts ret
earth
water
heart
 => nil
```